# Symfony 3 controller entity arguments

Tags: crud, symfony

After upgrading from Symfony 2.7 to 3.0.2, I have noticed the controllers from crud generator have changed.

Symfony 2 sample:

```
/**
 * Finds and displays a Article entity.
 *
 * @Route("/{id}", name="article_show")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Template("AppBundle:article:show.html.twig")
 */
public function showAction($id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entity = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Article')->find($id);

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Article entity.');
    }

    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);

    return array(
        'entity'      => $entity,
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    );
}
```

Symfony 3 sample:

```
/**
 * Finds and displays a Article entity.
 *
 * @Route("/{id}", name="article_show")
 * @Method("GET")
 */
public function showAction(Article $article)
{
    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($article);

    return $this->render('article/show.html.twig', array(
        'article' => $article,
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    ));
}
```

Not sure when exactly this has changed, as I didn't use crud generator when I was working with version 2.8.

Anyway, the magic I am interested is this:

```
public function showAction(Article $article)
```

which seems to be doing the same as earlier version of:

```
    public function showAction($id)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entity = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Article')->find($id);
        ...
    }
```

I couldn't find any documentation regarding this on Symfony website. Can someone explain how exactly this feature works and where I can find more info? Does it work for entities only, or...?

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature is called `ParamConverter` - read more here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html

In your controller you don't have `@ParamConverter` annotation because:

`If you use type hinting as in the example above, you can even omit the @ParamConverter annotation altogether`